# How do I debug a Jenkins agent launch error?

Tags: docker, jenkins, alpine-linux

I added a new worker/slave via a Docker plugin agent template that uses an Alpine image. The agent is instantiated, invoked, and authentication succeeds, but the launch of the agent on the slave fails with the following error (which I get from Jenkins > Nodes > my_node_id > See log for more details):

```sh
[03/27/19 18:11:39] [SSH] Authentication successful.
SSH connection reports a garbage before a command execution.
Check your .bashrc, .profile, and so on to make sure it is quiet.
The received junk text is as follows:
nologin: this account is not available

null
[03/27/19 18:11:39] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[03/27/19 18:11:39] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

There's not enough info for me to debug this - just the error output from some unknown command. Looks like the agent is issueing some command with a `nologin` parameter that is being misinterpreted as a userid. My guess would be it's some slave image configuration or package install problem.

Is there any way I can find out exactly what command(s) the agent issued? Any way to get more complete agent launch logs?

FWIW here's my slave Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker:stable-dind

RUN apk update; \
apk upgrade; \
apk add git; \
apk add python3; \
pip3 install pyyaml pexpect requests ruamel.yaml; \
apk add openjdk8; \
apk add curl; \
apk add sudo; \
apk add bash; \
apk add openssh-server; \
rm -rf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key; \
/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -A

EXPOSE 22

# Docker and Jenkins users
RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S docker; \
adduser -D -u 1001 -S appuser -G docker; \
addgroup -S jenkins; adduser -S jenkins -G jenkins; \
echo "jenkins:xxxxxxxxx" | chpasswd; \
chown -R jenkins:jenkins /home/jenkins

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `nologin: this account is not available` problem was because Jenkins agent requires bash, not sh. So changing the Dockerfile adduser fixed that problem:

`adduser -S jenkins -G jenkins --shell /bin/bash`

Now on to the next error :-)

Note I did not find out how to get more detailed info about the agent commands or logs. If anyone knows that I would be interested to know how.